# How to pass multiple parameters with e.target in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a onClick function in ReactJS, now I want to pass multiple parameters with e.target parameters. if I'm using multiple parameters then e.target is not working. How to do this?

My code:

```js
export const App = () => {
  const move_box_click = (x, y, boxHeight, boxWidth, e) => {
    console.log(x, y, boxHeight, boxWidth);
    console.log (e.target.id)
  };

return(
<>

<input
type="input"
id="email"
name="Email"
value={value}
onClick={()=>move_box_click(100, 95, 30, 100)}
/>

<input
type="input"
id="phone"
name="Phone"
value={value}
onClick={()=>move_box_click(100, 95, 30, 100)}
/>

</>
)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

also need to pass event

```
onClick={(event)=>move_box_click(100, 95, 30, 100,event)}
```